# Net::SMTP freezes on a certain server

Tags: perl, smtp

I have a Perl script for sending Emails:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP ();
use Email::Simple ();
use Email::Simple::Creator ();

my $smtpserver = 'server.com';
my $smtpport = 2525;
my $smtpuser   = 'test@server.com';
my $smtppassword = 'secret';

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
  host => $smtpserver,
  port => $smtpport,
  sasl_username => $smtpuser,
  sasl_password => $smtppassword,
  debug => 1,
});

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'myself@gmail.com',
    From    => "User name <$smtpuser>",
    Subject => 'Hello',
  ],
  body => "This is my message\n",
);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

It works on one server. But on another the script freezes. Debug messages are:

```
Net::SMTP>>> Net::SMTP(2.31)
Net::SMTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.29)
Net::SMTP>>>     Exporter(5.63)
Net::SMTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.31)
Net::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.31)
Net::SMTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.28)
```

What's wrong? How to debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if the TCP connection to the server was successfully established but the server does not send the expected SMTP greeting back. This can have several reasons, like:

- The server is not a SMTP server at all. If you try to use Net::SMTP against a web server (e.g. HTTP) you will see a similar result, because the HTTP server expects the client to send data first whereas with SMTP the server will send data first.
- The server has implicit TLS configured, that is it is waiting for the client to connect with TLS and not with plain SMTP. In this case the server is waiting for the client to start with the TLS handshake (i.e send ClientHello) before sending anything back.

I would suggest you look at the configuration of the server to see what is actually is expected.

Comment: The server is definitely an SMTP server. I connected to it from my local machine. But when I say: "helo server.com<enter>", it responds. When I connect to this SMTP server from the other server - it doesn't respond.

Comment: From this description I would suggest that the problem is at the server side then. It might be that the server will do a reverse DNS lookup for the IP of the client which then times out. Or it will check against some real time blocklist. Or there is a spamd or similar program which throttles the connection from unknown clients. Hard to say without information about the server, but I would not consider it a problem of Perl or Net::SMTP.